# Unique identifier for Windows OS Machine. (something like MAC address or Physical Address )

Tags: windows, networking, operating-system

I am creating a windows software with licensed version. There is a scneraio where once this license applied to windows-machine-1 it should be rejected if same license is applied in another machine.

I was planning to use MAC-Address to uniquely identify the machine but this MAC address is not unique across all network interfaces. Wifi, Ethernet, VMware network interfaces all have different mac address.

Is there any mechanism to uniquely identify the windows machine - it should not matter what network interfaces it use.?

Any OS level identification??